# Освобождение ресурсов в деструкторе C#

Tags: c#, mysql

В конструкторе объекта класса осуществляется подключение к БД MySQL, в деструкторе подключение закрывается. Допустимо ли подобное в C#?

Знаю, что, например, в java нет никакой гарантии, что метод finalize будет вызван. А как дела обстоят с деструкторами в C#? Будет ли соединение с БД корректно закрываться или же будет зависать при завершении приложения?

Как быть? Спасибо.

Comment: На сколько я помню, закрытие соединения нужно делать вообще всегда, когда закончился сеанс (выполнен запрос), следовательно закрывать подключение после того как класс обработает коллектор, не совсем корректно, так как даже при принудительном вызове диспоза, не факт что он корректно завершится, так как на него могут быть ссылки из других классов, а это может при водить к различным коллизиям. Правильнее, работать по следующему алгоритму: создал соединение. открыл, выполнил запрос, обработал данные из запроса, закрыл сеанс, очистил соединение.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C# и платформа .NET предоставляет программисту возможность освобождать захваченные ресурсы с помощью интерфейса `IDisposable` и оператора `using`. Это работает следующим образом:

1) Вы пишете класс и реализуете в нем `IDisposable`

```
public class Foo : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dispose called!");
    }
}
```

2) После этого вы исользуете `using`

```
using(var foo = new Foo())
{
    // ... do stuff
}
```

3) `using` компилятором разворачивается в следующее

```
var foo = new Foo()
try
{
    // ... do stuff
}
finally
{
    if (foo != null)
        ((IDisposable)foo).Dispose();
}
```

Таким образом, метод `Dispose()` будет вызван и освободит ваши ресурсы. В выводе мы конечно увидим

```
Dispose called!
```

Но вот вопрос: а что, если программист забудет использовать `using` для вашего класса? В имплементации выше ваш метод `Dispose()` тогда не будет вызван никогда, так как кроме как оператору `using` факт того, что вы реализовали `IDisposable` больше никому не интересен. Как с этим работать? Для этого есть финализатор. Финализатор - это аналог деструктора. Когда GC удаляет из памяти объекты, он особенно относится к объектам, у которых определен финализатор - они встают в отдельную очередь и, в итоге, GC вызовет финализатор при уничтожении объекта. С этом случае что можно сделать? Вот например такой класс

```
public class Foo : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dispose called!");
    }

    ~Foo()
    {
        Dispose();
    }
}
```

Но у этого класса явно проблема, ведь если программист использует `using` и вызывает `Dispose()`, и потом GC при удалении объекта вызовет финализатор который вызовет `Dispose()`, тогда получается `Dispose()` будет вызван дважды. Чтобы этого избежать, мы можем добавить вот жту строчку `GC.SuppressFinalize(this);` в `Dispose()` метод. Она говорит GC, что не надо вызывать деструктор объекта, так как он уже был вызван и ресурс уже освобожден. С таким фокусом наш класс превращается в

```
public class Foo : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        RealDispose();
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected void RealDispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dispose called!");
        // тут будет сама логика освобождения ресурса           
    }

    ~Foo()
    {
        RealDispose();
    }
}
```

С таким подходом, если программист вызовет `Dispose()` сам или с помощью `using` - то GC повторно его вызывать уже не будет. Если программист забудет это сделать, то GC вызовет очистку ресурсов через финализатор во время уничтожения объектов.

Теперь, отвечая на ваш изначальный вопрос, если вы создаете подключение к БД и сами его не закрываете, то это сделает за вас GC, но когда он это сделает - никто не знает заранее. Поэтому, если вы пишете класс и у него есть захваченный ресурс, то имеет смысл реализовать `IDisposable` освобождать ресурс в этот момент.

Но тут есть нюанс. Например, если вы захватываете такую вещь, как подключение к БД, которая сама по себе является классом, реализующем `IDisposable`, то вам нет никакого резона отпускать это соединение в финализаторе, так как если у вас вызван финализатор, то ваш объект на пути к смерти и, скорее всего, то же самое происходит и с подключением к БД, которое, кстати, может быть уже уничтожено GC. То есть, говоря о подключении к БД вот такой реализации будет достаточно

```
public class Foo : IDisposable
{
    SqlConnection conn;

    public Foo()
    {
        conn = new SqlConnection(....);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        conn?.Dispose();
    }       
}
```

Так как если программист вызвал `Dispose()` метод вручную (или через `using`), то подключение будет освобождено. Если программист это забыл сделать, то `Dispose()` метод никогда не будет вызван, зато GC вызовет финализатор класса `SqlConnection` и все равно его закроет и уничтожит, вы просто не будете знать когда он это сделает.

Подробнее про реализацию `IDisposable` можно почитать [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose).

Comment: А зачем выносить в отдельный метод `RealDispose()` вместо того чтобы вызывать `GC.SupressFinalize(this)` в конце метода `Dispose()`?

Comment: @yolosora не хочу вызывать это `GC.SupressFinalize(this)` в финализаторе

Comment: точно, я бы правда тогда ввел свойство IsDisposed

Comment: @yolosora зачем усложнять, вроде и без флагов нормально выглядит

Comment: да просто дело вкуса :)

Comment: Больше спасибо! Хочу задать вопрос около темы... некоторые говорят, что необходимо открывать соединение, делать запрос, соединение закрывать. После при необходимости вновь открывать для запроса и закрывать. Корректно ли это? Может я не понимаю.. но подключение же требует какие-то ресурсы (время, например), возможно, значительные или же нет?

Comment: @Имя открывайте каждый раз, когда вам нужно и закрывайте, когда заканчиваете работу. Когда вы думаете, что открываете соединение, на самом деле оно берется из пула соединений ADO.NET, а при закрытии возвращается в пул.

Comment: `conn?.Dispose();` - а зачем тут вопросик?

Comment: @Qwertiy на случай если его забыли создать, просто привычка.

Comment: Ну вроде в конструкторе создаётся. А то я уж подумал, может чего про конструкторы не знаю)

Answer (score 2):

В C# есть механизм, который может освобождать ресурсы при сборке мусора. В общем случае вам необходимо реализовать [паттерн освобождаемых объектов](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose).

Этот путь чреват тонкостями и сложностями. В худшем случае освобождение объектов будет происходить при сборке мусора, то есть в неопределённый момент времени. Памяти у вас может быть много, а подключений к БД всего 20 или 100, и все эти подключения могут быть заняты висящими в памяти объектами.

Альтернативой является использование IoC-контейнеров, таких, как Autofac, NInject, Castle, Unity.

Этот метод требует изучения. Рекомендую книгу Марка Симана Внедрение зависимостей в .NET. Она есть в переводе в бумажном виде, и, возможно, в электронном тоже ходит по просторам интернета.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, не стоит работать с подключением к БД через конструкторы и деструкторы. Открытие и закрытие подключение очень важные аспекты получения данных, которые желательно контролировать напрямую (не беру в расчет готовые ORM).
Если конкретнее отвечать на ваш вопрос, то вариант закрытия соединения в деструкторе возможен, но плохо для этого подходит, т.к. деструктор вызывается перед удалением объекта GC (сборщиком мусора), работу которого вы напрямую не контролируете. 
О том, как работать с подключениями можно почитать на [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/establishing-the-connection)