# Работа сборщика мусора в С# на примере использования деструктора

Tags: c#, сборщик-мусора

Всем привет и заранее спасибо за ответ, недавно начал изучать C# и встретился с темой сортировщика мусора, сам принцип работы как мне кажется понял, но вот написав для наглядности код понял что это не совсем так.

Я понял что в данном примере деструктор служит для нас индикатором того что объект удаляется, но вот смущает тот факт, что если поменять значение константы в цикле например вместо 100000 допустим на число побольше или поменьше, то строка кода `Console.WriteLine("Готово!");` может и не выполнится вовсе,хотя никаких условий которые бы препятствовали исполнению этой строчки нет...

Может есть какие тонкости работы сборщика мусора, но во всяком случае не понимаю почему игнорируется строчка кода `Console.WriteLine("Готово!");`.

```
using System;
class Destruct
{
    public int x;
    public Destruct(int i)
    {
        x = i;
    }
    ~Destruct()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Уничтожить " + x);
    }
    public void Generator(int i)
    {
        Destruct o = new Destruct(i);
    }
}
class DestructDemo
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Destruct ob = new Destruct(0);
        for (int count = 1; count < 100000; count++)
        {
            ob.Generator(count);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Готово!");
    }
}
```

Comment: [Освобождение ресурсов в деструкторе C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/993890/179763)?

Comment: почему вы решили, что она игнорирутеся, а не, например, выводится не последней?

Comment: @tym32167 ... и прокручивается в консоли, так что человеческий глаз не успевает ее прочитать?

Comment: @Igor как вариант

Comment: @tym32167  я поиздевался над собой и прочитал весь вывод, этой строчки нет ни в начале ни в конце ни в середине, хотя в некоторых случаях я наблюдал как сборщик мусора освобождал оперативную память перед тем как вывести на консоль"Console.WriteLine("Готово!");"

Comment: не надо издеваться над собой, просто направляйте вывод в файлик и в файлике ищите строчку. В консоли не все 100к строчек отображаются.

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо большое за ваш ответ думаю вы помогли мне Теперь осталось научиться направлять вывод в файл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выполнение финализатора недерминировано, как и всего процесса сборки мусора в целом.

Да, сборщик мусора обещает, что когда-нибудь он это сделает в будущем, но не говорит когда. Иными словами, когда вы выходите из цикла, то финализация может продолжаться, так как изменение ссылки не запускает моментально сборщик, так как эта операция очень накладная и ее проще выполнять, когда она действительно нужна.

Так же, само наличие финализатора замедляет сборку мусора, так как сборщик мусора при работе находит объект для утилизации и проверяет наличие финализатора. Если он есть, то объект помещает в очередь финализации, где поочередно у объектов вызывается финализатор `~`.

В данном случае, возможна ситуация, как написали в комментариях, что строчка "Готово" выводится, но она быстро пропадает из вида, так как активизируются финализаторы.

Поиск результата в консоли не имеет смысла с таким большим кол-вом выводимых строчек, так как консоль не бесконечна и зачищает результат предыдущих выводов.

Попробуйте выводить поток не в консоль, а в файл через [`File.AppendAllLines`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalllines?view=netframework-4.8).

Так же вам ничего не мешает поставить там точку останова в дебаггере и убедится, что она будет выведена.

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ