# Зачем использовать конструкцию using

Tags: c#, winforms

Я начал замечать, что часто люди используют:

```
using (Person p = new Person())
{

}
```

и посмотрев на это так и не понял, для чего это используется. В чем отличие от того, что я просто напишу `Person p = new Person()`

И еще кое что, когда только изучал формы, помню в конструкторе все писали, допустим

`listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;`

я это всегда удалял так как думал, что это бесполезно, но сейчас я подумал, вдруг в этом был заложен какой-нибудь гениальный смысл, который я не мог понять.

Comment: Документацию читали? Что там конкретно непонятно?

Comment: Хотелось бы услышать более понятным языком. Конечно же мне не нужен огромный текст. Просто сказать чем он лучше более компактной реализации. И тут еще есть второй вопрос на который вряд ли существует документация)

Comment: у вас два несвязанных вопроса - задавайте их отдельно

Comment: про dispose я как то писал [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/993890/179763), может будет вам полезно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном контексте `using` используют для объектов, реализующих метод `Dispose`, ограничивая этим оператором область их использования (фигурные скобки, конец метода). Чтобы избавиться от прямого вызова метода `Dispose`. Сборщик мусора будет доволен.